# Array issue out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I have tried so many variations of this code and I can't seem to get it correct.
I get an array out of bounds issue for the second if statement if I try something only with two parts. However, it works fine if there are 3 parts in the name.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class testArray 
{
   public static void main(String[]args)
   {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String fullName = input.nextLine();
        fullName = fullName + " " + " ";
        System.out.println(fullName);
        String [] parts = fullName.split(" ");
        String firstName = parts[0];
        String middleName = parts[1];
        String lastName = parts[2];
        String firstNameInitial = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();         //capitalizes first initial
        String middleNameInitial = middleName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();       //capitalizes second initial
        String lastNameInitial = lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();           //capitalizes third initial
        String initials = firstNameInitial + middleNameInitial + lastNameInitial; //Combines initials of name in capital form

        if (parts.length == 3)
        {
            System.out.println(initials);
            System.out.println(lastName.toUpperCase() + ", " + firstNameInitial+firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length()) + " " + lastNameInitial + ".");
            System.out.println(lastNameInitial + lastName.substring(1,parts[2].length()) + ", " + firstNameInitial+firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length()) + " " + middleNameInitial + middleName.substring(1,parts[1].length()));
        }

        if (parts.length == 2)
        {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the full stack-trace for your exception?  That should give you some pretty hefty clues...

Comment: I'm new to java. Posted the error in original.

Comment: Well, it would seem that `parts[2]` does not exist...

Comment: It means your firstName is null which is why you can not extract the substring. It is null because your split failed, and your split failed for reasons I do not know because you did not provide us with console input

Comment: why are you appending two white spaces `fullName = fullName + " " + " ";` ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because the way you initialize your variables:

```
String firstName = parts[0];
String middleName = parts[1];
String lastName = parts[2];
```

Here, if parts only has index 0 and 1 (a length of 2) you will get an exception because there is no `parts[2]` (it's index is out of bounds).

Modify that to something like this:

```
String firstName = parts[0];
String middleName = null;
String lastName = parts[1];
if (parts.length > 2) {
    middleName = parts[1];
    lastName = parts[2];
}
```

With this code, middleName will only be set if parts has a length greater than 2, which means that the index 2 will exist. Otherwise, middleName will be null (or you could change this to be an empty string or whatever you would like)

Comment: now I am getting
Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at initialOutput.testArray.main(testArray.java:16)

Comment: @RyanSchachte What should happen when the user don't have a middle name and only inputs "Ryan Schachte" for example? I think you should use if-statements to deal with that. For that particular exception, initializing middleName to `""` or `" "` will probably work, but in the long run you will need a strategy to deal with that.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the 3rd object in the array before you check how long the array is.

try this instead:

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

        public class testArray 
        {
            public static void main(String[]args)
            {
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String fullName = input.nextLine();
                fullName = fullName + " " + " ";
                System.out.println(fullName);
                String [] parts = fullName.split(" ");

                if(parts.length == 3)
                {
                    String firstName = parts[0];
                    String middleName = parts[1];
                    String lastName = parts[2];
                    String firstNameInitial = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();         //capitalizes first initial
                    String middleNameInitial = middleName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();       //capitalizes second initial
                    String lastNameInitial = lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();           //capitalizes third initial
                    String initials = firstNameInitial + middleNameInitial + lastNameInitial; //Combines initials of name in capital form
                    System.out.println(initials);
                    System.out.println(lastName.toUpperCase() + ", " + firstNameInitial+firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length()) + " " + lastNameInitial + ".");
                    System.out.println(lastNameInitial + lastName.substring(1,parts[2].length()) + ", " + firstNameInitial+firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length()) + " " + middleNameInitial + middleName.substring(1,parts[1].length()));
                }else{
                    System.out.println("error");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from here:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String fullName = input.nextLine();
    fullName = fullName + " " + " ";
    System.out.println(fullName);
    String [] parts = fullName.split(" ");
    String firstName = parts[0];
    String middleName = parts[1];
    String lastName = parts[2];
```

If someone enters text that is less than 3 words long, you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  You have to add something like:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String [] parts = null;
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Please enter first middle and last name");
        String fullName = input.nextLine();
        fullName = fullName + " " + " ";
        System.out.println(fullName);
        parts = fullName.split(" ");
        if (parts.length == 3)
            break;
    }
    String firstName = parts[0];
    String middleName = parts[1];
    String lastName = parts[2];
```

Which will prompt the user for three words until you get the right amount.

Comment: @RyanSchachte I tested your code with my code added, and it works fine.  See my update for what to add to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i think these line you want to put just after calling split:

```
String [] parts = fullName.split(" ");
if (parts.length == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("error");
                        return;
                    }
```

so the code would look like:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String fullName = input.nextLine();
                    fullName = fullName + " " + " ";
                    System.out.println(fullName);
                    String [] parts = fullName.split(" ");
                    if (parts.length == 2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("error");
                    } else if(parts.length == 3) {
                    String firstName = parts[0];
                    String middleName = parts[1];
                    String lastName = parts[2];
                    String firstNameInitial = firstName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();         //capitalizes first initial
                    String middleNameInitial = middleName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();       //capitalizes second initial
                    String lastNameInitial = lastName.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();           //capitalizes third initial
                    String initials = firstNameInitial + middleNameInitial + lastNameInitial; //Combines initials of name in capital form


                    System.out.println(initials);
                    System.out.println(lastName.toUpperCase() + ", " + firstNameInitial+firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length()) + " " + lastNameInitial + ".");
                    System.out.println(lastNameInitial + lastName.substring(1,parts[2].length()) + ", " + firstNameInitial+firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length()) + " " + middleNameInitial + middleName.substring(1,parts[1].length()));
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

i might suggest splitting on white space rather that " "
so for example 
        `String [] parts = fullName.split("\\s+");`

also why are you adding spaces (`fullName = fullName + " " + " ";`)

also you might not get to your parts comparison because you will hit the String extraction from the array first, put your if check (`if(parts.length == 3)`) straight after the splitting (`String [] parts = fullName.split("\\s+");`)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is here

```
String middleName = parts[1];
String lastName = parts[2];
```

You are appending two white spaces for fullName `fullName = fullName + " " + " ";` but actually these spaces won't append as there is no text after fullName, hence `parts` consists only one element at 0 position. and you are calling 1st position of parts array which is not available `String middleName = parts[1];` So you are seeing `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

0,1,2,3,4 >> these are indexed till 4 but the total components or length is 5 .

So In
firstName.substring(1,parts[0].length())

Here, "parts[0].length()" should be replaced by "parts[0].length()-1" because the previous is increasing the size by 1  and hence array is out of bound..

The same error u will get in next line.
So replace every .length with .length-1 ..

And remove this line

fullName = fullName + " " + " "; because it increases the length of variable path to 5 and hence it dosent goes in the if statements

Comment: I did executed ur program in c# . It run fine after i edited..

Console.WriteLine(lastName.ToUpper()   + ", " + firstNameInitial + firstName.Substring(1,parts[0].Length-1) + " " + lastNameInitial + ".");
                   Console.WriteLine(lastNameInitial + lastName.Substring(1,parts[2].Length-1) + ", " + firstNameInitial + firstName.Substring(1,parts[2].Length-1) + " " + middleNameInitial + middleName.Substring(1,parts[1].Length-1));

Comment: Actually, in Java the second parameter for String.substring is the end-index (excluded), so there's nothing wrong there. See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg .. oops yes . thnk u Simon . i thought this function are same in both .. :)